# vb.net Object(,) Array index won't find (0,0) even though it's an 11x37 array

Tags: vb.net, arrays, linq-to-sql, multidimensional-array, excel-interop

first time questioner here. Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

I'm trying to read a bunch of data from a spreadsheet, chop it up, then throw it into a database. I would rather not do things this way, but it's a basic reality of dealing with accountant-types. Thankfully these spreadsheet reports are very consistent. Anyway, I'm using LINQ for SQL to handle the object-to-reference stuff and I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop to get my Excel on.

I read through a directory full of .xls and for each one, I'm opening the file, getting a couple of specific data from some specific cells, and then getting a range of cells to pick out values.

```
Private Sub ProcessAFile(ByVal f As FileInfo)
    thisFile = openApp.Workbooks.Open(f.fullName)
    thisMonth = Split(thisChart.Range("D6").Value, "-").Last.Trim
    thisFY = thisChart.Range("L7").Value
    thisWorkArea = thisChart.Range("A14", "L51").Value2
    openApp.Workbooks.Close()
...
```

thisWorkArea was Dimmed as a global:

```
    Dim thisWorkArea As Object(,)
```

I'm getting both strings and ints in my range between A14 and L51, so making it an Object array makes sense here. I don't want to go through each row and pick out ranges in Excel, I want to just read it once and then close it.

So I'm getting the following exception:

System.IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array.

in this function:

```
Private Sub fillCurrMonth()
    Dim theseRows As Integer() = {0, 2, 3, 5}

    For Each i In theseRows
        Dim thisMonth As New Month
        'make sure category is in Database

        thisMonth.Dept = thisDeptName
        thisMonth.FY = thisFY
        thisMonth.Category = thisWorkArea(i, 0)
...
```

"Month" above refers to a LINQ entity. It's nothing fancy.

That last line there is where I'm catching the exception. In my watch, I find that thisWorkArea has a length of 456 and (0,0) -> "Inpatient"{String}

So why am I getting this exception? I put this in your expert hands. I'm still rather new to vb.net, so maybe I'm just missing something fundamental.

Comment: It would appear that you are setting "thisWorkArea" to the value of a cell when you call thisWorkArea = thisChart.Range("A14", "L51").Value2  In the debugger, after that line executes, if you hover over the thisWorkArea, what appears?  Is Option Strict On?

Comment: In the debugger, when I hover over thisWorkArea a tooltip pops up with {Length=456} next to the name. If I click the plus, it gives me the expected values of the spreadsheet with their coordinates, e.g. (0,0) "Inpatient". I am unfamiliar with "Option Strict On" but will see what that means.

Comment: I turned on Option Strict, made sure everything was typed the way it should be typed, and I'm getting exactly the same error here. Good to pick up another vb tip, though - thanks Chris Dunaway.

Comment: I found out from someone at work that with these arrays filled from Excel, the Watch reports them as having a 0-base when in reality they're 1-base. It's extremely bizarre, but I've accounted for it and it works now. Strange!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel uses 1-based indicies.  This stems from it using VB as it's in-app programming language which traditionally used 1-based indicies.

You'll find Excel returned an array defined as `thisWorkArea(1 To 11, 1 To 37) As Object`

Comment: Actually VBA can use _any_ base (eg Dim a(-7 to -3) as variant is valid).  It is the `Value` property of a `Range` object that returns a 1 based array

Answer (score 0):

```
        'Fix excel's 1 based index
        Dim oData(UBound(xData) - 1, UBound(xData, 2) - 1) As Object
        For i As Integer = 1 To UBound(xData)
            For ii As Integer = 1 To UBound(xData, 2)
                oData(i - 1, ii - 1) = xData(i, ii)
            Next
        Next
```